How do you get the SQL statement with variables replaced in Rails?
I'm using Rails 7.1.2 and I'm trying to figure out how to get Rails/ActiveRecord to do the variable interpolation into a SQL string and give me the resulting SQL back. Here's what I tried:
>> User.connection.to_sql("select * from users where id = $1", [1])
=> "select * from users where id = $1"
>> User.connection.to_sql("select * from users where id = ?", [1])
=> "select * from users where id = ?"
>> User.connection.to_sql("select * from users where id = :id", { id: 1 })
=> "select * from users where id = :id"
>> User.connection.to_sql("select * from users where id = :id", [{ id: 1 }])
=> "select * from users where id = :id"

The documentation for this method isn't clear about whether it is or isn't supposed to interpolate the bind parameters, it just says:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.8/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-to_sql

Converts an arel AST to SQL

I don't know if they mean SQL with the parameters interpolated or not when they say "SQL", but I don't know why else the method would accept bind parameters if it doesn't interpolate them.
I'm looking for any variation of the parameters in the query that will get replaced, so I would have the value of the bind parameters to be interpolated into the results, like this:
>> User.connection.to_sql("select * from users where id = $1", [1])
=> "select * from users where id = 1"


User.where("id=?", 1).to_sql or User.where(id: 1).to_sql

That's not how SQL bindings work. The whole point is that you pass the database a query and the values separately. This lets the database prepare and resuse the query and avoids SQL injection. Why do you think you want/need this?

What I'm doing is I have a complex query that I actually call with select_all, such as User.connection.select_all("select first_name from users where id = $1", nil, [1]). I'd like to be able to see the query with the parameters interpolated, but since that happens in the database, maybe there just is no way to do that in Ruby/Rails.

Hey Paul! To see it on the client, I think the AS Notifications should be one of the last things to happen before sending the query text. If so, you could make a subscriber class for “sql.active_record” events and log it. Here’s a blog post with a related example, for your case you wouldn’t want to filter only for slow queries though, but log all of them, maybe enabling your subscriber class on an as needed basis. https://kinsta.com/blog/logging-slow-queries/

While not built in to rails you could try and implement a simple version of this for yourself.
For Example:
def interpolate_sql_with_binds(sql, binds=[])
  sql_binds = sql.scan(/\$\d+/)
  raise ArgumentError, "incorrect number of bind values" if binds.size != sql_binds.size
  quoted_binds = binds.map {|b| Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(b).to_sql} 
  sql.gsub(/\$\d+/,sql_binds.zip(quoted_binds).to_h) 
end

interpolate_sql_with_binds("select * from users where id = $1",[1])
#=> "select * from users where id = 1"
interpolate_sql_with_binds("select * from users where id = $1 OR username = $2",[1,'engineersnmky'])
#=> "select * from users where id = 1 OR username = 'engineersmnky'"

Obviously you could continue to improve upon the error handling and syntax handling (e.g. IN() clauses, support for Array binds, etc.) as necessary.

Yeah, I've come to realize that Rails doesn't have a method for this, if I want to do this, I'd have create my own something like this

You're looking for sanitze_sql and friends from ActiveRecord::Sanitization::ClassMethods:
User.sanitize_sql(['select * from users where id = ?', 1])
# select * from users where id = 1

User.sanitize_sql(['select * from users where id = :id', id: 11])
# select * from users where id = 11

User.sanitize_sql(['select * from users where name = :name', name: "G'Kar"])
# select * from users where name = 'G''Kar'


What I really want actually is to get the SQL when using the bind parameters like this:
User.connection.select_one('select * from users where id = $1', nil, [1])
But at max pointed out, for that type of query that is using prepared statements under the hood, that interpolation doesn't happen in Ruby, it happens in Postgres, so it just might not be a thing

@pjb3 rails passes that off to pg. (After preparing the binds) See Here and PG::Connection#exec_params. Also see the libpq function
